# `KeyError:` when recursively parsing JSON -- error gives very little information

Tags: python, json, parsing, recursion

I am trying to recursively/flexibly parse any valid JSON object.  I'm getting an error using the below code with the below (further down) JSON example that doesn't make sense to me.  The below code currently outputs the output right below and then errors out.  The reason for the error is hard to pinpoint because the behavior on the first pass through is expected.  The second time, not so much...and the error is cryptic to say the least.

```
def get_level_keys(obj, level_count=0, level_keys={}): 
    key_list = list(obj.keys()) 
    print(f"key_list {level_count}: {key_list}")  
    level_key = f"{level_count}_level" 
    rem_keys = [] 

    for key in key_list: 
        if type(obj[key]) in [int,bool,str,float]:  
            level_keys[level_key].append(key) 
        else: 
            rem_keys.append(key) 

        level_keys[level_key] = [] 
        for key in rem_keys:  
            if type(obj[key]) == dict: 
                level_count += 1 
                get_level_keys(obj[key], level_count, level_keys) 

    return(level_keys)
```

Current output is:

```
key_list 0: ['fields', 'name', 'tags', 'timestamp']
key_list 1: ['LogEndOffset', 'LogStartOffset', 'NumLogSegments', 'Size', 
'UnderReplicatedPartitions']
```

...and then it errors with: `KeyError: '1_level'` (line 9: `level_keys[level_key].append(key)`).

Json for reproducing:

```
{
    "fields": {
      "LogEndOffset": 0,
      "LogStartOffset": 0,
      "NumLogSegments": 1,
      "Size": 0,
      "UnderReplicatedPartitions": 0
    },
    "name": "partition",
    "tags": {
      "host": "CUD1-001560",
      "jolokia_agent_url": "http://localhost:7777/jolokia",
      "partition": "22",
      "topic": "qa-connect-offsets"
    },
    "timestamp": 1591124460
  }
```

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: it means there is no key named `1_level` in `level_keys`, causing `level_keys[level_key]` to fail. If you want to read a key with a default value, use `level_keys.get(level_key, None)` -- Are you passing any thing to the other args for `get_level_keys` ? -- your value, `1_level`, doesn't exist in that JSON.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: to be pedantic, you aren't working with JSON at all. JSON is a text-based serialization format. You are working with a deserialized python data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it appears that `level_keys[level_key]` may be initialized to `[]` **after** it is referenced in the line

```py
level_keys[level_key].append(key)
```

Also, you may run the risk of adding a key multiple times so you should add a check for this.

Try rearranging your code to

```py
def get_level_keys(obj, level_count=0, level_keys={}): 
    key_list = list(obj.keys()) 
    print(f"key_list {level_count}: {key_list}")  
    level_key = f"{level_count}_level" 
    rem_keys = [] 

    # CHANGE IS HERE
    if level_key not in level_keys:
        level_keys[level_key] = []

    for key in key_list:
        if type(obj[key]) in [int,bool,str,float]:  
            # CHANGE IS HERE
            if key not in level_keys[level_key]:
                level_keys[level_key].append(key) 
        else: 
            rem_keys.append(key) 

        for key in rem_keys:  
            if type(obj[key]) == dict: 
                level_count += 1 
                get_level_keys(obj[key], level_count, level_keys) 

    return(level_keys)
```

### **Update:**

You also need to fix your recursion. Instead of performing `level_count += 1`, you should just use

```py
get_level_keys(obj[key], level_count + 1, level_keys)
```

Your code currently assigns a new level to each sub-key.

Comment: thank you.  I didn't realize you could use an expression as an arg to a function!  I will also try your other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the script is unable to find that key in the json object. You are recursively parsing this json but somewhere it expects to find the `1_level` key which fails. Can you perhaps share the initial data with which you call this method? Also what is the expected output? Hard to tell what its you are trying to achieve but try the below perhaps it might help.

```py
def get_level_keys(obj, level_count=0, level_keys={}, empty_dict={}): 
    key_list = list(obj.keys()) 
    print(f"key_list {level_count}: {key_list}")  
    level_key = f"{level_count}_level" 
    rem_keys = []

    for key in key_list: 
        if type(obj[key]) in [int,bool,str,float]:  
            if level_keys.get(level_key, None):
                level_keys[level_key].append(key) 
        else:
            rem_keys.append(key) 

        # level_keys[level_key] = 
        for key in rem_keys:  
            if type(obj[key]) == dict: 
                level_count += 1 

                get_level_keys(obj[key], level_count, level_keys, empty_dict) 
    empty_dict[level_key] = key_list
    return empty_dict
```